# Find in files and wrap with tag - Sublime

Tags: html, regex, replace, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have a number of links across my site that I'd like to wrap with some tags, I can find these links easily enough using RegEx, but when I go to replace with tags surrounding them I'd like the original href's to remain.

So I can find them like this:

```
<a class="button-link" (.+)>Back</a>
```

This will return a number of results like this:

```
   96  <div class="form-group">
   97    <a class="button" href="RegistrationSubmit.html">Save and continue</a>
  *98:   <a class="button-link" href="../employer.html">Back</a>*
   99  </div>
   100
```

But then if I put in the replace area:

```
<p>
  <a class="button-link" (.+)>Back</a>
</p>
```

That will simply replace every instance with the above code. What should I put in the "Replace" area? At present I have this:

[image]

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use `<a class="button-link" (.+)>` to select your tag. Try to match that against

   ```
   <a class="button-link" >Next</a><a class="button-link">Back</a>
   ```

   and you'll see [why](http://regex101.com/r/rZ1aV7).
2. Regexes aren't the best tool to parse HTML, but if you're careful and the usage is limited to easy input and manual use, you could use

   ```
   <a class="button-link" ([^>]+)>Back</a>
   ```

   and replace with

   ```
   <p>
     <a class="button-link" \1>Back</a>
   </p>
   ```

You are capturing the `href` in the first capturing group: to call it back in the replace the syntax is `\1`.

`[^>]` means "any character but a `>`" and will prevent the regex to "get out" of the current tag.